# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

**i updated Newtonsoft.Json package as 9.0.1
and at my local server publish file working very well.but my boss said it is not working on live server.Could you please solve this issue.**

```
Event code: 3005
```

Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 7/13/2021 7:46:08 AM
Event time (UTC): 7/13/2021 7:46:08 AM
Event ID: 90c697ce232647939806d6e807833f1e
Event sequence: 2
Event occurrence: 1
Event detail code: 0

Application information:
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-2-132706359680241249
Trust level: Full
Application Virtual Path: /
Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DRS\
Machine name: EC2AMAZ-7HRKLBA

Process information:
Process ID: 8776
Process name: w3wp.exe
Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DRS

Exception information:
Exception type: TargetInvocationException
Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__b(IAppBuilder builder)
at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IAppBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) at Hangfire.Common.SerializationHelper.Serialize(Object value, Type type, SerializationOption option) at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.SerializeJob(Job job) at Hangfire.RecurringJobEntity.GetChangedFields(Nullable`1& nextExecution)
at Hangfire.RecurringJobEntity.IsChanged(IReadOnlyDictionary`2& changedFields, Nullable`1& nextExecution)
at Hangfire.RecurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(String recurringJobId, Job job, String cronExpression, RecurringJobOptions options)
at Hangfire.RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate[T](Expression`1 methodCall, String cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo timeZone, String queue)
at Comsol.Champ.DRS.Web.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in D:\Projects\DRS\DRS\DRS\DRS\DRS.Web\Startup.cs:line 29
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Request information:
Request URL: http://referal.champdonate.ie/
Request path: /
User host address: 185.233.17.193
User:
Is authenticated: False
Authentication Type:
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DRS

Thread information:
Thread ID: 10
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DRS
Is impersonating: False
Stack trace:    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__b(IAppBuilder builder)
at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IAppBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

Custom event details:

Comment: Something still has a reference to Newtonsoft.Json version 4.5. Double check your update and check all references in all projects

Comment: i checked but have no extra Newtonsoft.Json text in project

Comment: I just had this yesterday. check your web.config.  I had one that required a specific (old) version.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your web.config or app.config for any sections that look like this. It will force your web server to use an older version of a DLL.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

You can fix it by, First, making a backup of your config file.  Next, remove the `bindingRedirect` line.